# How Calling Functions with lots of args in Assembly Works

Tags: c, linux, function, assembly, x86-64

Here is an example set of functions, the first with 20 args the second with 2:

```
int a(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5, int n6, int n7, int n8, int n9, int n10, int n11, int n12, int n13, int n14, int n15, int n16, int n17, int n18, int n19, int n20) {
    return n1 * n2 * n3 * n4 * n5 * n6 * n7 * n8 * n9 * n10 * n11 * n12 * n13 * n14 * n15 * n16 * n17 * n18 * n19 * n20;
}

int b(int n1, int n2) {
    return a(n1, n2, n1, n2, n1, n1, n2, n1, n2, n1, n1, n2, n1, n2, n1, n1, n2, n1, n2, n1)
      + a(n1, n2, n1, n2, n1, n1, n2, n1, n2, n1, n1, n2, n1, n2, n1, n1, n2, n1, n2, n1)
      + a(n1, n2, n1, n2, n1, n1, n2, n1, n2, n1, n1, n2, n1, n2, n1, n1, n2, n1, n2, n1);
}
```

It gets [compiled](https://godbolt.org/g/jHvMgc) to this assembly:

```
a(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int):
  push    rbp
  mov     rbp, rsp
  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], edx
  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], ecx
  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], r8d
  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], r9d
  mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+16]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+24]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+32]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+40]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+48]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+56]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+64]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+72]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+80]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+88]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+96]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+104]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+112]
  imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+120]
  pop     rbp
  ret
b(int, int):
  push    rbp
  mov     rbp, rsp
  push    rbx
  sub     rsp, 8
  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], edi
  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], esi
  mov     r9d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, eax
  call    a(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
  add     rsp, 112
  mov     ebx, eax
  mov     r9d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, eax
  call    a(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
  add     rsp, 112
  add     ebx, eax
  mov     r9d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  push    rdi
  mov     edi, eax
  call    a(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
  add     rsp, 112
  add     eax, ebx
  mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  leave
  ret
```

I have a few questions about this. First, I noticed that it sort of seems to switch how it handles the args as the number increases:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
...
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
...
```

Wondering what is going on there, why it is doing that. It seems to treat the first arg with `push`, then the next 8 or so with `mov`, then the remaining with `imul` only relative to the `eax` register. Wonder if there is a limit to how many args you can have.

The second thing I'm wondering is the following. Say instead of `a()`, the function `b()` called out to some "system function" or some other external library call. Wondering how does it know how to unpack the args. Well, I guess, nevermind, I assume the C compiler will compile into assembly/machine code all linked external libraries. So yeah nevermind there I guess.

The last thing is if the syscalls all have a set number of arguments, similar to how in x86 the max operands is 3. Or perhaps the syscalls can have any number of arguments. It seems they would want to limit it for performance, so they only use those earlier stage instructions like `push` and `mov`, instead of `imul`.

Thanks for the help, just looking for clarification on how arguments are handled when calling functions in assembly, especially when there are a large number of arguments.

Comment: What operating system and architecture are you programming for?  Please tag both as the answer to your question is going to vary greatly depending on these details!

Comment: Read the ABI document for your platform, it should tell you how function arguments are passed exactly.  As you failed to say what architecture and operating system you are programming for, I can unfortunately not link you to the ABI document relevant for your platform.

Comment: The 64-bit System V ABI that Linux uses(Which your godbolt example is targeting) says how this works.Since you are using all integer class parameters the first 6 are passed in registers RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R9, R10 and then the remainder are pushed on the stack in right to left order. There is a summary of the ABI here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI .A complete copy of the latest ABI can be found here: https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI (you want the x86-64 one)

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at the optimized version using `-O3`  . https://godbolt.org/g/k7qFjJ

Comment: A version using optimization where function `a` isn't inlined into function `b` is here: https://godbolt.org/g/evBV38

Comment: @MichaelPetch interesting, thank you for that.

Comment: @LancePollard yea, in general case optimizing makes the code usually easier to read since the compiler does not need to store the argument variables into local memory to aid the dummy debuggers...

Comment: FWIW, *"If you have a procedure with 10 parameters, you probably missed some." — Alan Perlis*

Comment: lol, very nice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to learn more about stack frame and application binary interface (ABI, or calling convention). ABI defines the way parameters are passed by the caller to the callee, which registers are volatile, as well as how the stack is cleaned up.

Many ABIs exist, because anyone can design their own ABI as long as the caller and the callee agree. However, only a few ABIs are widely used. On Windows most 32-bit programs use stdcall, cdecl, Microsoft's fastcall or Borland's fastcall, whereas 64-bit programs mostly use Microsoft x64 calling convention. On Unix 64-bit programs always use System V AMD64 ABI, which is also the one used by your compiler.

Let's look at your code, with comments:

```
push    rbp                     ; save the old stack frame
mov     rbp, rsp                ; establish new stack frame
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi  ; save the first six arguments
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], edx
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], ecx
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], r8d
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], r9d
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]  ; load n1
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]  ; eax = eax * n2
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12] ; eax = eax * n3
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+16] ; eax = eax * n7
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+24] ; eax = eax * n8
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+32]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+40]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+48]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+56]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+64]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+72]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+80]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+88]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+96]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+104]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+112]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+120]
pop     rbp                      ; restore old stack frame
ret                              ; exit
```

Note: the first two line has nothing to do with the arguments; they are to create a stack frame, so that you can easily access local variables and arguments. Without the stack frame you can still access them with [rsp+*], but the offset need be adjusted according to any `PUSH` and `POP` you used.

Following that are instructions to store the arguments to local variables. Registers are frequently changed and arguments passed in registers need to be stored, in case you need to use them later. In this case, however, is not necessary. So the optimized code can be

```
push    rbp                     ; save the old stack frame
mov     rbp, rsp                ; establish new stack frame
mov     eax, edi                ; eax = n1
imul    eax, esi                ; eax = eax * n2
imul    eax, edx                ; eax = eax * n3
imul    eax, ecx                ; eax = eax * n4
imul    eax, e8d                ; eax = eax * n5
imul    eax, e9d                ; eax = eax * n6
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+16] ; eax = eax * n7
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+24] ; eax = eax * n8
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+32] ; eax = eax * n9
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+40]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+48]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+56]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+64]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+72]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+80]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+88]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+96]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+104]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+112]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+120]
pop     rbp                      ; restore old stack frame
ret                              ; exit
```

From the above example, you should be able to guess that the first argument is passed in `edi` (or `rdi`, `di`, `dil` depends on the size), the second one is in `esi`, and then `edx`, `ecx`, `r8d` and `r9d` (Integer only, floats are passed in vector registers). When you have more than 6 arguments, the other are pushed on to the stack and can be accessed using [rbp+16], [rbp+24], .... ([rbp+8] is old rbp; [rbp] is returning address).

For the caller

```
mov     r9d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]  ; r9d = n6
mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]  ; r8d = n5
mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]  ; ecx = n4
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]  ; edx = n3
mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]  ; esi = n2
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]  ; eax = n1  ; will assign to edi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]  ; push n20
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]  ; push n19
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
push    rdi
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]  ; push n7
push    rdi
mov     edi, eax                 ; edi = n1
call    a()                      ; call the function
add     rsp, 112                 ; clean up the stack, 14 * 8 = 112 bytes
mov     ebx, eax                 ; result is in eax
```

a more straightforward version is

```
mov     r9d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]  ; r9d = n6
mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]  ; r8d = n5
mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]  ; ecx = n4
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]  ; edx = n3
mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]  ; esi = n2
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]  ; edi = n1
push    [rbp-12]                 ; push n20
push    [rbp-16]                 ; push n19
push    [rbp-12]
push    [rbp-16]
push    [rbp-12]
push    [rbp-16]
push    [rbp-12]
push    [rbp-16]
push    [rbp-12]
push    [rbp-16]
push    [rbp-12]
push    [rbp-16]
push    [rbp-12]                 ; push n8
push    [rbp-16]                 ; push n7
call    a()                      ; call the function
add     rsp, 112                 ; clean up the stack, 14 * 8 = 112 bytes
mov     ebx, eax                 ; result is in eax
```

Note that the arguments are pushed in reversed order.

Since you can push any number to the stack (before it overflows) before you call the function, there is no limitation on the number of arguments.

Comment: `push rbp` also goes away when optimizing: `-fomit-frame-pointer` is enabled at `-O1` and higher.  And of course `b(n1, n2)` just inlines `a`.  clang CSEs the sub-products in `b()` into fewer total multiplies (https://godbolt.org/g/6wWr6M).  ICC reorders `a` because multiply is commutative, lowering latency at the cost of more `mov` instructions.

Comment: If you made `__attribute__((noinline)) a` or didn't provide a definition, then an optimized `b()` wouldn't spill its args to the stack in the first place.  You'd have `push rdi` / `push rsi` pairs, and some reg-reg moves.  Even when gcc and clang don't inline `a` into `b`, they notice it's pure and CSE the three calls: calling once and multiplying by 3.  https://godbolt.org/g/vrDW6Y.  (Unlike if you hid the definition, so it would have to assume `a()` had side effects.)